# Installing some package via JPSM

Tags: javascript, angular, jspm

I'm using `jspm` in my web app. I want to install `npm:angular2` package without configuring in `config.js` file. Because I don't need to load angular2 module via jspm, just added angular2 library manually. Like this:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/npm/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

How can I add jspm package to my`package.json` without configuring in `config.js` file?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install and add it just to package.json file do:

```
npm install --save angular2
```

--save saves it in your "dependencies" section in the package json file

Comment: Thank you @MarkPieszak. Currently I have that solution. So my project has two `package.json` file, because angular2 should be located in sub directory. I do `npm install` twice. Does npm install sub directory's npm packages ?

Comment: Anything in package json that has its own package json with dependencies will get installed. Yup!